# Manim SquareToCircle Example Scene Renders Blank Video

Tags: python-3.x, manim

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, Python3.7 on a Virtual Box VM. I have followed the instructions that is [given here](https://github.com/Elteoremadebeethoven/AnimationsWithManim/blob/master/English/0_instalation/gnuLinux/INSTRUCTIONS.md)

However, when I reach the last step and try to run this command

```
python3.7 -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
```

everything seems to be working perfectly, till the ultimate video is shown. The video is blank with 0 zero length.

I have browsed through similar questions on this forum but all have been facing errors in the last step. 
I have not faced any errors. These are the prompts:

```
soham@minux:~/InstallManim/manim-master$ python3.7 -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
Media will be written to ./media/. You can change this behavior with the --media_dir flag.

File ready at /home/soham/InstallManim/manim-master/media/videos/example_scenes/480p15/SquareToCircle.mp4

Played 3 animations
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon investigation, found out H.264 decoder was not installed on my system.